# Android: SSLContext SSL implementation not found

Tags: android, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android NoSuchAlgorithmException: “SSLContext SSL implementation not found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826535/android-nosuchalgorithmexception-sslcontext-ssl-implementation-not-found)

Has anybody experience with this error in Android? It is thrown by this line:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, yes. See [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/49c4994b27e99a33/c97e0a78baafe37a). [This discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/76d6125d80faefc1/b87bef60a2d56cc3?#b87bef60a2d56cc3) may also be relevant.

Comment: So Apparantly you have to use TLS like so:
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");